# Input a grid made of chararcters into a double array

Tags: java, arrays

My problem requires me to input this grid into a character double array

```
.#....

..#...

..#..#

...##.

.#....
```

I have tried using the basic row and column for loops

Here is my code :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < columns ; j++){
        grid[i][j] = s.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(grid[i][j]);
    }
}
```

The code is only outputting the first column of the grid and then throwing a NoSuchElementFoundException. I'm not sure what's wrong with it, is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: `The code is only outputting the first column of the grid` The first column?  Or the first row?

Comment: `s.next().charAt(0);` will be trying to read a new String, where as you want to keep this String for each row

Comment: You're not thinking through your logic fully on paper before committing it to code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels [Memories](https://www.amazon.com/Sparco-2-Inch-Green-Inches-SPR02177/dp/B009YZJCDS)....

Answer (score -1):

In your example the `s.next()` call grabs the next row (not character) every time it is called, so you must save off the row and then index the characters of the row in the column loop.

The following should work for what you want assuming the row and column size has been set correctly:

```java
char[][] grid = new char[rows][columns];
for(int i = 0 ; rows; i++){
    String row = s.next();
    for(int j = 0 ; i < columns; j++){
        grid[i][j] = row.charAt(j);
        System.out.println(grid[i][j]);
    }
}
```

The code follows: for each row index `i`, read the next row from the file and then for each column index `j` take the character for the current column index from the row and finally place it in the grid array.

You may also want to use `s.nextLine()` instead of `s.next()` since your input is separated by lines as this will avoid reading in any new line characters such as `\n` or `\r`

Comment: Please explain your answer. Understand that an answer's explanation is 1000 times more important than an answer's code, and that the posted code should mainly serve to illustrate the concepts in your explanation. The purpose of this site is not to do someone else's homework for them but to create a question/answer repository for common problems **for future visitors**.

Comment: I'm typing with my phone so I'm adding and editing as I go. Bear with me please.

Comment: My goal since I'm on my phone is to quickly give an answer first that can help the poster, then I add to it afterwards so that it can clarify the reasoning and answer all parts of the question. If this is wrong then I can focus on the whole answer from now on. This way has just been easier for me so that I can look back at the post and make sure I address everything asked.